# ¿Por que mi programa se cae al declarar un array grande en C?

Tags: array, c

estoy intentando conseguir datos para poder graficar la complejidad algorítmica de shell sort.
Lo que hace el programa es almacenar datos desde otro archivo (en esto no hay problema) pero al momento de crear el array con "x" cantidad de datos simplemente el programa se cae y no responde.
La verdad esto tiene un tope, aproximadamente para un array con 520.000 espacios el programa se cae, para inferiores ningún problema.

El programa es el siguiente y N es la cantidad de espacios que tiene el array que serán llenados con datos (solo números).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void llena_array(long int *array,int n);
void muestra_array(long int *array,int n);

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Cuantos datos? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long int a[n];
    
    llena_array(a,n);
    //muestra_array(a,n);

    int temp=0,i,j,gap;
    time_t t_1,t_2;
    
    t_1=time(NULL);
    //shell sort
    for(gap=n/2;gap>=1;gap/=2){
        for(j=gap;j<n;j++){
            for(i=j-gap;i>=0;i=i-gap){
                if(a[i+gap]>a[i]){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[i+gap];
                    a[i+gap]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    t_2=time(NULL);

    printf("\nCantidad de datos = %d",n);
    printf("\nTiempo Total = %lf\n",difftime(t_2,t_1));  

    //printf("Luego de shell sort..\n");
    //muestra_array(a,n);
}

void llena_array(long int *array,int n){
    FILE *entrada;
    int i;
    int dato;
    entrada = fopen("datos_ordenados.txt","r");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &dato);
        array[i] = dato;
    }
    fclose(entrada);
}
void muestra_array(long int *array, int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```

¿Que podría hacer para evitar/solucionar este problema?,quisiera poder obtener el tiempo de ejecución con 600.000 datos pero no he podido, y la verdad no conozco muy bien sobre el tema.

Invocando shell_sort desde cmd de windows 10
[image: Imagen demostrativa]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La declaracioón `long int a[n]` crea una variable **local**, las cuales se almacenan en la pila.

Para 520000 elementos, ya que cada uno ocupa 8 bytes (es el tamaño de un `long int`), necesitas del orden de 4MB. Eso es puede ser demasiado espacio para la pila (depende de límites impuestos por el compilador o el operativo).

Cambia `a` para que sea un `long int *` y luego usa `a = malloc(n*sizeof(long int))`. Eso reservará espacio en el *heap*, en el cual hay mucha más capacidad. De todas formas verifica si el resultado almacenado en `a` es `NULL`, pues eso indicaría que `malloc()` tampoco ha podido encontrar memoria suficiente.

No es necesario tocar el resto del programa. Un puntero a `long int` puede ser usado en cualquier lugar donde podías usar un array de `long int`.

Comment: Me a servido totalmente ya no se cae,¿sabes con que palabras podría buscar mas sobre el contenido que me has dicho (pila,heap) en algún libro?, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aparte de 'pila' y 'heap', dices? :-) Mmm, memoria dinámica, almacenamiento de las variables, ... Pila en ingles es stack, y heap en español a veces lo he visto traducido como 'montón', pero suelo verlo mas en inlgles, por eso lo escribí así.